# Convert CSV charset from Shift-JIS to UTF-8

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, utilities

## What I want to do

1. Fetch data from a CSV file (charset: Shift-JIS)
2. Convert the charset to UTF-8
3. Set the values into Google Spread Sheets

I have a problem on step 2.

## Issue

I'm having a trouble converting Shift-JIS CSV to UTF-8 CSV.
The strings in Google Spread Sheets are all garbled.

Here is my code and screenshots of Google Spread Sheets:

```
function myFunction() {
  const fileId = 'xxxxxx' // Shift-JIS CSV file's ID
  const blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
  const csv = blob.getDataAsString();

  const newBlob = Utilities.newBlob('', MimeType.CSV).setDataFromString(csv, 'UTF-8');
  const newCSV = newBlob.getDataAsString();

  const values = Utilities.parseCsv(newCSV);

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

**Expected:**
[image: Ideal]

**Instead of:**
[image: Actual]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in your script, it is required to retrieve the values from the file (CSV data of shift-jis) as `shift-jis`. In this case, `const newBlob = Utilities.newBlob('', MimeType.CSV).setDataFromString(csv, 'UTF-8');` is not required to be used. So when your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const fileId = 'xxxxxx' // Shift-JIS CSV file's ID
  const blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();

  const csv = blob.getDataAsString("shift-jis");  // Modified

  const values = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getDataAsString(charset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getdataasstringcharset)